# ClamAVをインストール中ですが、./configure --enable-check を実行するとエラーが出ます。

Tags: ubuntu

**現象**
ClamAVをソースコードからビルドしてインストールしている途中です。`./configure --enable-check`を実行すると下記のエラーが出ます。

```sh
checking for CHECK... no
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking check.h usability... yes
checking check.h presence... yes
checking for check.h... yes
checking linking with check... configure: unable to compile/link with check
configure: error: 

ERROR!  Check was configured, but not found.  Get it from http://check.sf.net/
```

**期待値**
エラーを解消して`./configure --enable-check`を完了させたいです。

**再現手順**
下記リンクの通りです。OSはLubuntu 20.04 LTSです。
[Installation on Debian and Ubuntu Linux Distributions](https://www.clamav.net/documents/installation-on-debian-and-ubuntu-linux-distributions#Users-and-on-user-privileges)

**追記1**
`check`はインストール済です。

**追記2**
`dpkg -l check`の出力結果です。

```sh
dpkg-query: check に一致するパッケージが見つかりません
```

ちなみに、`sudo apt-get install check`でインストールしました。

Comment: 答えはもうログ中に書かれているような `check` を http://check.sf.net/ からインストールしてください

Comment: @774RR checkはインストール済です。

Comment: 手元の環境(`Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`)で試してみましたが、質問欄にある様なエラーは発生しません。ただ、記事にある `check-devel` パッケージは `Ubuntu 20.04` では提供されておらず、`check` パッケージに static link library(`*.a`) と header file(`*.h`) が含まれています。

Comment: `check` がどのようにインストールされているのか知りたいので、`dpkg -l check` の出力結果を [edit] から追記いただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis static link libraryと　header fileが含まれている、ということはどういうことでしょうか？お手漉きで説明して頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 追記しました。

Comment: @atago_IT `dpkg --listfiles check` を実行すると、`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheck.a` や `/usr/include/check.h` などが表示される、という事です。「追記2」の内容を読む限り、`check` パッケージがインストールされていませんね。

Comment: `configure` の実行前に前提条件としていくつかのパッケージのインストールが必要なようですが、こちらは漏れなく実施していますか？ (`check` パッケージもこの中に含まれてます) / `apt` 経由で clamav のパッケージも用意されているなか、敢えてソースコードからのコンパイルを選ぶのであれば、それ相応の知識が必要となってきます。

Comment: @metropolis `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheck.a`も`/usr/include/check.h`も表示されます。

@cubick 前提条件もすべてインストールしています。
`apt`経由でインストールしてみますね。

Comment: `apt`経由でインストールしました。皆様ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

目的が「ClamAV のインストール」なのか「自力で ClamAV をソースコードからコンパイルする」なのかが分かりづらいですが、コメントでのやり取りを踏まえて別解を投稿しておきます。

---

Ubuntu を含めてメジャーなディストリビューションであれば ClamAV は **パッケージとして提供されている** ので、システム管理の面でもパッケージマネージャを通してインストールする方が手軽でおすすめです。

**Ubuntu の場合:**

```
$ sudo apt install clamav
```

なお、ソースコードからのコンパイルはパッケージでリリースされたものより最新のコードを利用したい場合などに限られます。

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg -l check` の出力を見る限り、`check` パッケージがインストールされていません。

`sudo apt install check` などのコマンドで `check` パッケージのインストールを試みてください。既に試されたとのことですが、おそらく失敗しているので出力に成功ログが出ているかを確認してください。

典型的なのは「パッケージ ほにゃらら が見つかりません」というエラーで終わっている場合です。インストール前に `sudo apt update` でパッケージ情報を更新するのを忘れていた場合などに出ます。

Comment: `sudo apt update`でパッケージ情報を更新した上でインストールしてみたのですが、`checkはすでに最新バージョンです`と出ます。